# Всплывающая форма при клике на элемент. HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на блок около него всплывала форма(что-то вроде подсказки).
Вот пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

При повторном клике по квадрату блок будет прятаться:

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var inner = document.querySelector(".box__inner");
box.addEventListener("click", function() {
  inner.classList.toggle("block");
});
```

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box__inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 80px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__inner">
    Текст
  </div>
</div>
```